# MariaDB and Hikari connection breaks partially

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mariadb, hikaricp

Good morning,

Currently I am encountering a very strange problem, which I am not able to solve on my own:

I've hosted an MariaDB in AWS and my Application is using Hikari Pool for handling connections. The configuaration is listed below.

The problem is, that after a few hours (randomly) the connection seems to be broken but not really broken.. Hard to explain, but all reading operations are still working while all write operations fail with the following exceptio. For me it sounds like the Transaction part is broken. I am by far not an expert, but after a lot of testing it seems related to my AWS, as it does not happen on my local computer...

```
 java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=6211) Socket error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
  at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:293) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
  at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:359) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
  at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.sendQuery(StandardClient.java:506) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
  at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.execute(StandardClient.java:635) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
  at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.execute(StandardClient.java:511) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
  at org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:196) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:401) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
  at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:72) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                    |
  at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                   |
  at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                    |
  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.enlistInCurrentTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:414) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                |
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:392) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]                                                                                                                                         |
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:355) ~[BackendService-1.4-all.jar:na]
```

Hikari Configuration

```
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=carIdentConnectionPool
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 20
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000 (1sek)
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=3000 (3sek)
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout= 20000 (20sek)
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

Comment: Seems to be an infrastructure problem, which would off topic in Stackoverflow. Try adding a validation query to mitigate it.